# Facebook Share only when web app is live with valid url?

Tags: facebook

Just a quick query (I'm new to fb sharing) - I can't find any reference to it on the web. I'm creating a quiz app. I've added the code to share the quiz result, but I don't have an app domain yet.

Am I correct in thinking that I will require the app domain before I can really test to see if its working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you share links, then those URLs must be publicly reachable, if you want the Facebook scraper to read them and extract the Open Graph meta data, yes.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the reply!

OK, sounds like I need to wait until I have a domain where the quiz app is going to sit. The FB popup demands that I have a href parameter, so I guess i'll have to wait. 

So just to be clear I suppose there is no way to actually see if the data/content from the site or app is posting on FB until it goes live and I add the domain...

Comment: You don’t need to set the app live to be able to test, and you can post links to any domain you like (unless you specifically excluded that via app settings.)

Comment: Ok cool. I guess it's not working because I'm trying to post from my local files.

Thanks